# How to call action of Controller outside the controller in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I am using Xajax in Zend Framework. I need to call action of particular controller in function of Xajax Class I have created.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not place the action code you need to call into the model and then call it from there within the action and wherever else like:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->methodToCall();
```

Comment: No. It will not work this way. Actually I am using xajax. I have created a Global class in which I have written code for Xajax implementation. And from this class I want to call action of the controller. So is there a way in Zend for calling action of particular controller outside MVC scope ?

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery. It makes AJAX easy.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/my-controller/my-action',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Successful response');
  }
});
```

In Zend Framework, create a controller action that you want to call using AJAX and send a response body that you want to use (either XML, JSON, or HTML for example).